# Xcode 9 custom table view cell constraint configuration on storyboard

Tags: uitableview, swift4, xcode9

I have been adjusting the constraints for a custom table view cell and I am not getting the output I want. This is what I have so far:

[image]
[image]

I didn't add the constraints yet for the number labels. And this is what I have in the UITableViewController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "SummaryCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SummaryCell")

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88
}
```

As for the size inspector describing the SummaryCell.xib file, I set the Table View Cell row height to be 88, with the custom box checked, and the view has a "Show" of "Frame Rectangle," with a width of 414 and height of 88, which I am building for a iPhone 7+/8+ view and shows up fine without constraints. I know constraints will be needed for other screens sizes, and adjusting constraints has been a nightmare so far. Can anyone help?